# Does resharper has the same function as find actions in Intellij idea?

Tags: resharper

In intellij idea, I can use Ctrl+shift+A to find the action that I did not know the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

This has just been added to ReSharper 9. See "Go to Action" under "Navigation Improvements" in [this blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/10/13/introducing-the-resharper-9-early-access-program/). You can hit Alt+Enter and just start typing.